# 3d coordinates + shade

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, mesh

I am trying to plot a 3D coordinate system (X,Y,Z) and then I would like to shade an area within this 3D coordinate system with some color for example shade the following region defined by:

Z > Y > X

Can anyone please help?

I have done the following but cant seem to know how to proceed,

```
a=0:0.1:10;
b=0:0.1:10;
c=0:0.1:10;
[x,y,z]=meshgrid(a,b,c);
```

Comment: No ofense, but you havent tried anything. Show us some effort! :P

Comment: if I knew how to, I wouldn't have asked ;) @AnderBiguri

Comment: Yes, I guess. But in stackoverflow in general you need to show what you have tried on order to get some help. Additionally your post have very little infromation. can you show us at least what do you expect to get?

Comment: Thanks. I am new here. Having this 3D coordinate system I would just like to shade or color the points that satisfy a certain condition. for example a condition X<Y<Z. I know how to draw in 3D but this is different. In 2D shading a region that satisfies a certain inequality is easy. @AnderBiguri

Comment: See if the answer fits you. Your question needs some volumetrical approach, it seems

Comment: Then accept the answer that most suits you. click in the tick next to the number in hte post ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you need to be able to plot volumetric data then. The best thing you can do is download [vol3d](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22940-vol3d-v2) in order to achieve that. Its a quite nice voxel visualizer.

then:

```
a=0:0.1:10;
b=0:0.1:10;
c=0:0.1:10;
[x,y,z]=meshgrid(a,b,c);

shaded_area=false(size(x));

% Your rules

shaded_area=y>x;           % two ways ;).
shaded_area(z>y)=true;

% Plot it!
vol3d('Cdata',shaded_area);
```

However, as you are triying to plot volumetric *boolean* data I suggest you use this couple of nice things in order to get a "nicer" visualization, no more.

```
vol3d('Cdata',smooth3(uint8(shaded_area),'gaussian'))
axis([0 length(a) 0 length(b) 0 length(c)])
view(122,14)
axis off
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you call shading, this can be a starting point:

Create a 3D grid of points and a logical 3D array satisfying your condition:

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:100,1:100,1:100);
ShadeRegion=(Z > Y).*(Y> X);
```

Then use the built-in function `isosurface`:

```
fv = isosurface(X,Y,Z,ShadeRegion,0.5);
```

You can then apply the example in displaying isosurfaces available in [the manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html):

```
p=patch(fv);
set(p,'FaceColor','red','EdgeColor','none');
daspect([1,1,1])
view(3); axis tight
camlight 
lighting gouraud
```

Result:

[image: shaded region]