# 3d visualisation of clusters of 1's

Tags: matlab

I have a N x N x N matrix of 1's and 0's in Matlab and I want to plot only the 1's, like in [this picture](http://s1295.photobucket.com/user/Theophilos0/media/sample4matl_zps0dfb8787.png.html) (ignore the axes):

[image]

Any advice?

**Edit:** Thank you for the immediate answer. What if I want to count the size (minimum and maximum diameter) of each cluster or its surface area?

Comment: Using `isosurface` might solve your problem. See this answer for an example of 3D-rendering a binary matrix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26166979/2777181

Comment: @Jigg haha we are each of us promoting our answer given in that question. Actually isosurface will work also.

Comment: @AnderBiguri yep. I haven't tried your option, but it looks like it does the job as well.

Comment: Post another question with your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestions of @Ander Biguri and @Cape Code above, I have the following code, where size(state) = N N N

```
p = patch(isosurface(state,0));
isonormals(state,p)
set(p, 'FaceColor','r', 'EdgeColor','none')
daspect([1 1 1])
view(3)
axis vis3d
axis([1 N 1 N 1 N])
camlight
lighting phong
alpha(0.5)
```

I think that's exactly what I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to go for [vol3d v2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22940-vol3d-v2). Its a nice Volumetric visualizer, however it wont give you those smooth blobs, but "pixelated" blobs.

Usage:

```
vol3d('Cdata',data)
```

It has more options, read the function help.