# Measurments on clusters of 1's

Tags: matlab

I have a N x N x N matrix of 1's and 0's in Matlab, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240673/3d-visualisation-of-clusters-of-1s). 1's form clusters, in the sense that a group of 1's is seperated from any other 1 by at least one 0. I want to count the size (minimum and maximum diameter) of each cluster, its volume and its surface area and also to count the number of clusters and tag each one (cluster 1, cluster 2 etc.). Are there any ready matlab functions to help or should I follow a procedural approach?

Answer (score 2):

[`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) will get you close, though some functions are only implemented for 2D. For example, if you have an array `clusterArray`

```
lblArray = bwlabeln(clusterArray); %# tags each cluster

%# get some measurements directly
stats = regionprops(lblArray, 'Area', 'Centroid', 'BoundingBox'); %# look at the help for more info

%# for other measurements, loop over the clusters
for iLabel = 1:max(lblArray(:))
   currentCluster = lblArray == iLabel; %# clusterArray with single cluster
   %# your code here..
end
```

Comment: I haven't thought to consider the array as a B/W image. As I see, both of the functions you propose work in 3D. Thank you!

Comment: @Theo: Every array is an image, every image is an array.